# Liferay JIRA Integration

Tags: integration, liferay, oauth-2.0, jira, opensocial

I am trying get JIRA gadgets onto Liferay Portal. But I am facing issues in JIRA accepting Public key.

In Liferay:

- I generated public key using Puttygen and saved the public key under:

  *liferay folder/data/opensocial/rsaSigningKey.pem.*
- Published a Jira gadget (Activity Stream) through:

  *Liferay -> Control Panel -> Portal settings -> Opensocial gadget publisher*

  Then:

  *Actions -> Manage OAuth -> Selected RSAPrivate*

  and set the consumerkey as rsaKeyName as mentioned in portlet.properties

In Jira:

- Opened:

  *Jira -> Application Links -> created new Generic Application*

  *Liferay -> Incoming Authentication consumer key - rsaKeyName consumer
  Name - Liferay Public key*
- Gave the public key text in rsaSigningKey.pem callback.
- Callback as mentioned in Liferay opensocial gadget
  portlet.properties.
- When I tried to save the settings, I get an error in Jira:

  > "Must be a valid public key. java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key
  >   format".

Where am I going wrong?

How are you generating public and private key?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue integrating Jira and Jenkins. The documentation is really unclear across the board.  One thing that might help: when you paste the public key into Jira make sure there are no extra spaces. Endlines are OK but remove all spaces.